# Nesting a fragment in a nested fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I start out with a fragment with a framelayout that I replace for a child fragment. This chlid fragment has a listview, when I click the list view I want to replace this fragment with yet another child fragment.

From what I have read I should do this by replacing the framelayout from the first parent fragmen, but this framelayout is not reachable from the child fragment. 
What is the right thing to do here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the actual `View` instance, just the resource id of the container:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new ChildFragment()).commit();
```

or a better solution design-wise is to notify your parent `Fragment` about a selection in the `ListView` and ask it to replace `Fragments`:

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new ChildFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: For the first solution. I have tried this ans it works but when I try to use childfragmentmanager it fails. Isn't it correct to use CFM here?

Comment: You should use getChildFragmentManager() in parent Fragment and getFragmentManager() in child Fragments to reference the same FragmentManager.

Comment: For the second answer, yes I could di that, but wouldn't the new child fragment become a sibling to the other? Plus i would love to have the fragments more decoupled. Is it really good design to have the fragment call its parent to create a child for itself?

Comment: Yes, sorry, seems like I misunderstood your question, thinking there is just one level of nesting. However having and indefinite level of nesting doesn't seem a good idea to me, so you should probably come up with a better design decision..